# How can I print code and output using TeXworks?

Tags: texworks, printing

When I use TeXworks and I want print the code I have seen there is not the possibility to print the code and the output. A few years ago I printed the code using TeXworks but now there is no possibility to do it in the menu.

[image]

I've seen all the tabs but there's nothing about how I can print the code with the default colors. For the output there is the possibility to print but

[image]

*why have I this dialog box that prevents me from printing directly from the viewer?*

I have very happy to receive an answer. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Not an answer: You can create a new LaTeX document, input your source using listings and print the PDF ;)

Comment: @TeXnician Thank you very much for your kindness. I remembered that you could print directly.

Comment: @TeXnician Hi, actually I am not able to do it with your suggestion.

Comment: My suggestion is to create a new LaTeX document. In that use the `listings` package and `\lstinputlisting` with proper LaTeX highlighting options to input your source file (the one you wanted to print). Then run pdfLaTeX on it, it will output a PDF. That can be printed (not from TeXworks, it doesn't support printing PDFs currently).

Comment: @TeXnician Ah, for this reason I not understood. I never have used listings package. Welcome always any answer(s).

Comment: @TeXnician Hi, please, can you put an answer for me? Thus I vote it. I not am able to do with your comment.